# Using ref as useMemo dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to reference a `ref` object inside a `useMemo` callback. This is the code I tested with as I have seen from other similar questions.

```
export default function App() {
  const divRef = useRef();

  useMemo(() => {
    console.log(divRef.current);
    return divRef.current;
  }, [divRef]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(divRef.current);
  }, [divRef]);

  return <div ref={divRef}/>;
}
```

The console will output `undefined` inside `useMemo` and output `<div/>` inside useEffect. It seems like even though the dependencies are identical in the two, the check-diff timing is different. I just want to be able use the `ref` inside `useMemo` when the div has rendered, and update the memoized value. But it doesn't seem to be triggering a second calculation. Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: `useEffect()` runs after the intial mount of your component, so the div would've been created allowing you to access it, whereas the `useMemo()` on the first render will run before, so it'll be empty. What is it that you're trying to do within the `useMemo()`, a ref doesn't need to be supplied as a dependency to it as it's stable, meaning that `divRef.current` will always give you the most up to date value